# How can I properly parse this XML file with xPath in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

This is my XML file that I need to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2002-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2003-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2004-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2005-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2006-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2006-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2007-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2008-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I want to show every book and its information that has a publish date after 2005. and the price is bigger than 10.
This is my Java code:

```
package xml;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException, FileNotFoundException {

        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xPath = factory.newXPath();

        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile("catalog/book[publish_date>2005]/price | catalog/book[price>10]/price");

        File xmlDocument = new File("Books.xml");
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(xmlDocument));
        
        Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)result;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Info: " + nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
        }

    }

}
```

How should I do this properly with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it right.  The problem is that, according the specification, a numeric comparison (`<` or `>`) requires implicitly converting each operand to a number.  A node’s text content is only a valid number if it consists entirely of ASCII digits, with an optional leading minus, optional period, and optional surrounding whitespace.

A date like `2002-12-16` obviously does not qualify.  However, you can turn that into a string that can be implicitly converted into a number, using [substring-before](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-before):

```
XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(
    "catalog/book[substring-before(publish_date,'-')>2005 and price>10]/price");
```

Answer (score -1):

Take advantage of the XML date format and do a string comparison there, annd combine your conditions

```
/catalog/book[(publish_date > '2005') and (number(price) > 10)]
```

And thus

```
XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile("/catalog/book[(publish_date > '2005') and (number(price) > 10)]");
NodeList bookNodes = (NodeList)xPathExpression.evaluate(inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < bookNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Element bookElement = bookNodes.item(i);
    System.out.println("Author: " + bookElement.getElementsByTagName("author").item(0).getNodeValue());
}
```

You'll need to add the remaining, necessary tags. Also, if you book elements might no all contain all expected node, you'll need to check the collection returned by getElementsByTagName()

Comment: how should I do that exactly? I'm new to this

Comment: Node cannot be converted to Element? Or am I just using the wrong package?

Comment: if I use bookNodes.item(i) instead of bookElement in System.out.println, I dont have .getElementsByTagName() function

Comment: The NodeList will only give you nodes, which could be a TextNode, Element, CDataNode etc. But from your schema you know that 'book' will be an Element, so that's a safe cast

Comment: Have you tried the whole code with the XML file? Because when I run the project I don't have any information in the console. I should get the last three books from the XML file.

Comment: @jova, no, I trying to help you without access to a computer right now. Can you debug and verify that your XML is loaded in the InputSource? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: This will not work.  A `publish_date` node cannot be converted to a number.  (And `number(price)` is not necessary, since the node will be converted to a number automatically.)

Comment: The code that I posted in the question worked but didn't execute what I wanted. There are no exceptions

Comment: @VGR How should I do it?

Comment: @VGR, for the record, that's why I suggested comparing 'publish_date' to the *string* '2005', not the number. It's a bit cheap, taking advantage of the XML date format allowing for string sorting. I like the more explicit substring-before approach better.